# Reset Moving Button on JavaScript When he arrive to the end of the page

Tags: javascript, html

I'm try to make a button that move right from the start of the page to 
the end of the page.
example
:
image clean page with a button

(Button) [ now the button need to move on the page in the same line 
to end of the page and when he will get there he will "reset" and start doing that again

(Button)     {his moving>>> }  (Button) {moving>>>} (Button) {his moving>>> }  (Button)      and here Reset

and now he will start do the same task again

(Button)     {his moving>>> }  (Button) {moving>>>} (Button) {his moving>>> }  (Button)      and here Reset

and again ..

(Button)     {his moving>>> }  (Button) {moving>>>} (Button) {his moving>>> }  (Button)      and here Reset

I did button that move right but I don't know why its don't stop and I really don't know how to make it reset.

This is the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <title>Moving Button Page</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script src="js/script.js"></script>    

    </head>

        <body>
          <button id="movingid"  style="position: absolute;left: 0px;">i Am Moving Button</button>

        <!-- <button id="moveit"  onclick="move()" style="position:absolute;margin-right="5%"">Let Start Moving</button> -->

        </body>
    <footer>
    </footer>
</html>
```

And this is The JavaScript

```
function doMove() {
     var times = 10
     var movingid =  document.getElementById("movingid");
     var leftpx = parseInt(movingid.style.left);
     var i=0
        if (i<=times) {
        for(var i=0 ; i<=times ; i++){
            console.log(i)
       movingid.style.left = leftpx + 50 + 'px';
          // clearInterval(stop);
        }

}
        else{
            clearInterval(stop);
        }
}
```

Comment: *** i Ment To Write Reset in the title ***

Comment: You can go back & *edit* your question btw - its not 100% clear what your asking.

Comment: Typo: `onclick="move()"` with a function called `doMove()` is not correct

Answer (score -1):

`<marquee direction="right"><button>Moving Button</button></marquee>`

http://jsfiddle.net/oe95k35u/ 
I guess you want this.

I can't understand that why are you making your code complex by using javascript , this is also possible with HTML5.

Comment: what your code is doing is by click on then button ... the button move right .and by click agian he back ...i want the button to move alone to right until the end of the page .... and i i want to see the button moving .

Comment: So What do you want ? 
Your question was too weird. first you wrote I want to stop it,now explain what do you want to do?

Comment: Welcome :) I edited my answer,kindly vote it up and accept as answer, so it can help people :))

Comment: Isn`t marquee html elment considered deprecated ?

Comment: Sorry I had no idea about that @michal Lach ..
Omer Malka you can use JQuery plugins for this https://remysharp.com/2008/09/10/the-silky-smooth-marquee